# Group by and nested array with php/eloquent/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Say that I have a time based dataset, which contains an array of data like this:

```
{
   "group": "a", "date": "2017/01/01", value: 0.01
},
{
   "group": "a", "date": "2017/01/02", value: 0.02
}
```

How can I produce a result set like this:

```
{
    "group": "a", value_sum: 0.03, timeline: [["2017/01/01", 0.01], ["2017/01/02", 0.02]]
}
```

and so on.

I'm using Eloquent ORM, and I'm currently stick to a pattern where I make two different queries, the first to get the sum for each distinct group:

```
SELECT group, sum(value) FROM table GROUP BY group
```

and the second one to get the trends:

```
SELECT group, date, sum(value) FROM table GROUP BY group, date
```

then I merge the two results set in php.

I'm looking for a way to get all results in one query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing a `GROUP BY` with rollup:

```
SELECT
    `group`, date, sum(value)
FROM table
GROUP BY
    `group`, date
WITH ROLLUP
```

In Laravel:

```
DB::table('table')
    ->select('`group`', 'date', DB::raw('sum(value) as sumval'))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('`group`, date WITH ROLLUP'))
    ->get();
```

You can check the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html) to see how group by with rollup works.  For the current structure of your queries, rollup would generate additonal rows for the subtotals of the value for each `group`.  In addition there would be a grand total row on the bottom of the result set.  While you *could* also achieve the same thing with two separate queries, you might find it easier to let MySQL do the heavy lifting for you.  After all, it was created for this very purpose.

One other note: *Don't* name your columns `group`, because this is a reserved MySQL keyword.  Also, don't name tables `table`.  Perhaps you just used those names as placeholders, but if not you'll have to escape them everywhere.

Comment: Yes, using WITH ROLLUP let me spare one sql query.
Thanks.